# Long polling: Multithreading the php backend file

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, backend, long-polling

I am working on a chat site which will include **Friendship**, **Private Messaging** and **Notifications** system, for these I will use **Long polling / Comet**..

Method is simply, Ajax will open connection to a backend file and will keep connection alive until there is an update, So far everything is fine... 
**T**he problem occurs when two tabs open connection to the same backend file,  So

`Tab A` opens connection and keeps **backend** file busy and since php is single thread the `Tab B` waits for `Tab A` to close its connection from the **backend** file so `Tab B` can use it. it causes both tabs to stop working and eventually make the website unusable.

What is the best experience to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used long polling, so my answer may seem biased.
However, it sounds like your project would benefit a lot more from using web sockets.

Here is a great library to help you get started:
http://socket.io/